# How to add new lines/update data to the yaml file with python?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I want to update my .yaml file and in each iteration new data added to my .yaml file while previous data is still saved, here is piece of my code:

```
import yaml

num=0
for i in range(4):
    num +=1    
    data_yaml =[{"name" : num,  "point" : [x, y , z]}]

    with open('points.yaml', 'w') as yaml_file:
        yaml.dump(data_yaml, yaml_file)
```

and this is my target output result which I want to achieve in my **points.yaml** file:

```
- name: 1
  point: [0.7, -0.2, 0.22]
- name: 2
  point: [0.6, -0.11, 0.8]
- name: 3
  point: [0.4, -0.2, 0.6]
- name: 4
  point: [0.3, -0.7, 0.8]
- name: 5
  point: [0.1, -0.4, 0.2]
```

How to append or add automatically new lines beside previous data in .yaml file ?

Comment: Try switching from `w`rite mode to `a`ppend mode in your `open` call. Relevant doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open.

Comment: @n8sty Unless you know exactly what you are doing, it isn't a good idea to append to an existing file containing a YAML document. The chances are that you end up with a file that can no longer be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the expected output your root level data structure is a sequence. In your
Python program you should therefor start with an empty list. (In case you didn't
know that, the easiest thing to do is `.load` the YAML document that you
hand-crafted and see how it ends up as data structure Python.)

Not only do you seem to be using a version of Python that is EOL, but also old
(compatibility) routines for ruamel.yaml. If you cannot change the former, at
least start using the new ruamel.yaml API:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import ruamel.yaml

points = [
  [0.7, -0.2, 0.22],
  [0.6, -0.11, 0.8],
  [0.4, -0.2, 0.6],
  [0.3, -0.7, 0.8],
  [0.1, -0.4, 0.2],
]

data = []

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')

num=0
for i in range(5):
    num +=1
    x, y, z = points[i]
    data.append({"name" : num,
    "point" : [x, y , z ]
    })

    with open('points.yaml', 'w') as yaml_file:
         yaml.dump(data, yaml_file)

with open('points.yaml') as yaml_file:
    print(yaml_file.read())
```

which gives:

```
- name: 1
  point: [0.7, -0.2, 0.22]
- name: 2
  point: [0.6, -0.11, 0.8]
- name: 3
  point: [0.4, -0.2, 0.6]
- name: 4
  point: [0.3, -0.7, 0.8]
- name: 5
  point: [0.1, -0.4, 0.2]
```

Please note that I changed the argument to `range()` to 5.